# Why does my write() print a blank text file rather than the content - webscraper

Tags: python

My code is returning a blank text file without the items which should be printed in the file. Running the file in anaconda, the text prints inside the file, so I don't think it is a problem with the retrieval, but something wrong with my write() code. I am new to python, any help would be well received. Thanks in advance.

```
import bs4 
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 

my_url = 'https://www.globaltimes.cn/content/1190338.shtml'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs each news item
page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"span12 row-content"})

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"span12 row-content"})

filename = "first chinese scrape.txt"
f = open ('D:/myfirstpython.txt',"w")

headers = "data"

f.write(page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"span12 row-content"})
)

f.write('containers')
f.close()
```

I tried another method through this, but it still yielded a blank text file.

```
from newspaper import Article
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
url= 'https://www.globaltimes.cn/content/1190338.shtml'
article = Article(url, language="en") # en for English 

article.download()
article.parse()
article.nlp()

print("Article Title:") 
print(article.title) #prints the title of the article
print("\n") 
print("Article Text:") 
print(article.text) #prints the entire text of the article

file1=open("NewsFile2.txt", "wt")
file1.write("Title:\n")
file1.write(article.title)
file1.write('Article Text:')
file1.write(article.text)
file1.close()
```

Comment: File write should be a string or bytes, currently, you are trying to write a bs4 object into the file.

Comment: @SauravPanda, would it be possible to write the contents of 'containers' as a string? I am trying to write the whole findAll("div",{"class":"span12 row-content"}) to a text file. *thanks for your response.

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if it helps, if you need some other info, let me know!

Comment: @SauravPanda I entered your code, saw another blank text file, so I deleted both myfirstpython.txt and first chinese scrape.txt, and tried again with your code. Still it presented me a blank file, once opened in notepad. Perhaps there is something wrong with my system.

Comment: Can you try using file path as: "myfirstpython.txt" 

This will store the file in your local directory along with the python code

Comment: @SauravPanda I've uploaded the code here at [link] (bfin.dev) - can you please take a look? I think it should work, but still I am facing the same issue. Can you see any issue in the code?

Comment: I am actually unable to see the link, can you just put that link on your question?

Comment: @SauravPanda i solved it, I am not sure how, sometimes it would save a 0 bytes file, but now it works... I will edit it with the working code in the question

Comment: @traderliam No, don't edit the answer inside the question. Either accept any answer that helped you, or post the answer yourself. But don't edit the answer inside the question

Comment: @Tomerikoo I don't have enough rep to upvote his answer, I didn't see the part to post the answer myself. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want as your final output. but currently you are tring to write an object to the file which is incorrect. Try the below snippet:

```
filename = "first chinese scrape.txt"
f = open ('D:/myfirstpython.txt',"w")

headers = "data"
for k in page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"span12 row-content"}):
    f.write(k.text)

f.write('containers')
f.close()
```

This will give you the following output in the file: (file content below)

> Photo: ICBrowsing recent reports and commentaries on China in Indian media, one wouldn't be surprised to find that they are riding
>   on unwarranted Western criticism of China and exploiting every chance
>   to find fault with China.One column in WION, published on May 19,
>   calls on India to back Taiwan's participation in the World Health
>   Assembly (WHA), in line with a number of countries led by the US,
>   regardless of the internationally recognized "one China" principle. In
>   the Swarajya magazine, an article published on Monday calls on India
>   to take a swaying stance in the China-US feud over Hong Kong and not
>   support "one China" one-sidedly.Obviously, the Indian media has been
>   keeping a sharp lookout on China, believing every move by China in
>   South Asia is a plot against India, and every one of China's actions
>   on the world stage has implications for India's regional and
>   international standing. As the world continues the arduous fight
>   against the coronavirus, some Indian observers have gone so far as to
>   blame China for the outbreak. The overemphasis on or even resentment
>   toward China reflects the anxiety of Indians. India considers itself
>   the No.1 power in South Asia and is reluctant to see other countries
>   have more influence in the region. In addition, driven by an
>   opportunistic mind-set, some Indians believe they can benefit from
>   China's rivalry with the US-led West and strike a balance. The call of
>   some Indian media outlets to back Taiwan's participation in WHA, hold
>   China accountable for the coronavirus outbreak and take advantage of
>   Hong Kong affairs are close follow-ups of Western policies against
>   China, reflecting the lack of independent thinking of some Indian
>   media. But will the West spare any real interests to India? That's a
>   big question mark. While Western forces are willing to see animosity
>   between China and India, the Indian media has played a considerable
>   role in creating misunderstandings between the two Asian giants.India
>   and China do share similarities and differences. It is imperative that
>   they find ways to accommodate their differences. As the global power
>   balance shifts toward Asia, a cooperative relationship between the two
>   largest Asian economies can enhance their influence in the region and
>   beyond, while conflicts between the two will only be exploited by the
>   West to jeopardize their interests. Indian media should enhance their
>   understanding of China and work on more balanced coverage on China and
>   help build constructive relations. It is also hoped that they can
>   shake off Western influence and think independently so that they can
>   best maintain India's interests. 
>       containers